# How can i find closed-form formula of this

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, closed-form

Tell me please if I'm doing this right way and if , so where my mistakes come from, because I ran out of ideas where to look at.

$a_0 = 10$

$a_1 = 10$

$a_n = 4a_{n-2} - 2^n \cdot n^2, \quad \text{for } n \geq 2$

Firstly I found homogeneous equation which came up to be

\begin{equation}
\frac{15}{2} \cdot 2^n + \frac{5}{2} \cdot (-2)^n
\end{equation}

After this I tried to find closed-from formula for this

\begin{equation}
a_n^p=4a_{n-2}^p-2^n*n^2\\
a_n^p-4a_{n-2}^p=-2^n*n^2\\
\end{equation}
and i let:
\begin{equation}
a_n^p=(An^2+Bn+C)*2^n\\
a_{n-1}^p=(A(n-1)2+B(n-1)+C)*2^{n-1}\\
a_{n-2}^p=(A(n-2)^2+B(n-2)+C)*2^{n-2}\\
\end{equation}
after i got my n-2 and n element i wanted to find them

\begin{equation}
(An^2+Bn+c)2^n-4(A(n-2)^2+B(n-2)+C)2^{n-2}=-2^nn^2\\
\end{equation}
after i divide both sides by $2^n$ and multiply by $2^2$
i get that
\begin{equation}
16An-16A+8B=-4n^2
\end{equation}
which gives me after i put $n=2$ and $n=3$
\begin{equation}
A=-5/4\\
B=-3/4
\end{equation}
which in reality doesnt check if i plug any n's to my final result which looks like that
\begin{equation}
a_n=\frac{15}{2} \cdot 2^n + \frac{5}{2} \cdot -2^n(-\frac{5}{4}n^2-\frac{3}{4}n)
\end{equation}

Comment: In fact, you have two sequences. You could concentrate your study on one of them.

Comment: What do you mean by the fact that i have 2 sequences and could only concentrate on one

Comment: Set $u_n=a_{2n}$ and $v_n=a_{2n+1}$. You can study sequences $u_n$ and $v_n$ in a separate manner... and begin for example by $u_n$

Comment: The solution is $2^{n+3}+(-1)^n2^{n+1}-\frac{2^{n-1}}3(n^3+3n^2+2n)$.

Answer (score 2):

The **general** solution for the homogeneous equation is $a_n = a 2^n + b (-2)^{n}$.  You do not want to plug in the initial values yet.  You need to first find a particular solution.

Now you shouldn't get a particular solution of the form $(A n^2 + B n + C) 2^n$, because $2^n$ is a solution of the homogeneous equation.  Instead you should try $a^p_n = (A n^3 + B n^2 + C n) 2^n$.

Then add the general solution of the homogeneous equation, and plug in the initial values to find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: thanks you’re right i slightly misunderstood some steps but now i see it very clear